# If friction and normal force are both the components of contact force, shouldn't the friction be repulsive?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, forces, friction, adhesion

Is friction due to intermolecular attractive forces or repulsive ones.
Since both friction and normal force are the components of contact forces, shouldn't friction be repulsive.

Comment: why should it be repulsive ?

Comment: first two paragraph of this answer of mine answers your question. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/592860/271783

Answer (score 1):

For a force that is directed perpendicular to a surface the designations “repulsive” and “attractive” have clear meaning. Repulsive is in the outward normal direction. Attractive is in the inward normal direction.

For a force that is directed parallel to a surface those designations lose meaning. Which direction is “attractive” parallel to a surface?

Friction can neither be attractive nor repulsive since those terms do not have meaning for forces parallel to a surface.

Comment: Ok, is it true that contact force arises due to repulsions between the electron clouds of atoms/molecules of surfaces in contact. And since normal force is repulsive, so I tried to ask that books write that friction arises due to attractive intermolecular forces, so it is due to attractive intermolecular forces or repulsive.